# Quantum Game Theory

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

This is a request for recommendations. I want to learn quantum game theory. Can anyone suggest where to begin with, some reading materials. (I am well versed in Non-Cooperative Game Theory, so you can assume my aptitude.) That would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**An Introduction to Quantum Game Theory**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0506219.pdf) by J. Orlin Grabbe.

There is also [a related question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/135796), answered by [Steven Landsburg](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/250/steven-landsburg) (also a member of Econ.SE) that might be of interest to you.